# MySQL query update with subquery multiple values

Tags: mysql

I need to update a table based on the result of a subquery that brings more than 1 value, but with the query below I get the error return "Subquery returns more than 1 row". I would like to know if it is possible to make a "loop" to update the values ​​with each result presented in my subquery below.

Complete Query

```sql
UPDATE estoque_tamanhos tam 
SET tam.qtde = tam.qtde - IF(NEW.tipo = 'K', NEW.qtde_prod * NEW.qtde_lote, NEW.qtde_prod)
WHERE tam.estoques_id = (SELECT estoques_id 
                         FROM combo_estoque 
                         WHERE produtos_id = NEW.produtos_id) 
  AND UPPER(tam.tamanho) = UPPER(NEW.tamanho_prod);
```

Subquery that returns 2 or more values.

```
SELECT estoques_id FROM combo_estoque WHERE produtos_id = NEW.produtos_id
```

Result

| produtos_id | estoques_id |
| --- | --- |
| 246 | 54 |
| 246 | 207 |

In the ideal scenario, my query would execute the first value, after the second ... third ... without repeating the previous ones.

Comment: Change `WHERE tam.estoques_id = (SELECT estoques_id ...` to `WHERE tam.estoques_id IN (SELECT estoques_id ....`

Comment: @forpas I tried this, but return "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"

Answer (score 0):

You should create a stored procedure using **Cursors** to iterate each result of your query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATING_ROWS(PRODUTO_ID INT, qtde_prod INT, qtde_lote INT, TIPO INT) 
BEGIN
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE estoque_;
   DECLARE cursor FOR SELECT estoques_id FROM combo_estoque WHERE produtos_id = NEW.produtos_id) AND UPPER(tam.tamanho) = UPPER(NEW.tamanho_prod)
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

   OPEN cur1;
   read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cur1 INTO estoque_;

      IF done THEN
         LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;

      UPDATE estoque_tamanhos tam SET tam.qtde = tam.qtde - IF(TIPO = 'K', 
      qtde_prod * qtde_lote, qtde_prod)
      WHERE tam.estoques_id = estoque_;
   END LOOP;
END
```

You have to create a stored procedure like this to iterate each result of your select query. You can read more about this in this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html)

Comment: I tried this but return "Syntax error", can you check?

Comment: It was an example, I didn't run it to test if really works because I don't have your database.